# 2 TP-Link routers, 2 private DHCP-based networks: Static Routing does not work

Tags: routing, home-networking

I have two TP-Link routers. 
TP-Link Router #1: `172.16.0.1` (DHCP 172.16.0.100 - .254) 
TP-Link Router #2: `192.168.0.1` (DHCP 192.168.100 - .254)

Client A is connected through LAN to Router #1, and gets IP `172.16.0.101` . 
Client B is connected through LAN to Router #2, and gets IP `192.168.0.100`.

Now Client B wants to connect to the SSH server/Port 22 on Client A.

On Router #2, I setup a Static Routing to `172.16.0.0/255.255.255.0` through the gateway `192.168.0.200.`

But when I do a Diagnostic on Router #2 to `172.16.0.101`, I just get a timeout. TP-Link Router #1 does not respond. Neither Client A/Port 22 does.

**What do I miss?**

[image]

Comment: How are the two routers interconnected? The static route could be exactly the reason it doesn't work.

Comment: @TomYan The 2 routers are connected though Ethernet cable.

Comment: Have you also set up a static route on router #1 pointing it to 192.168.0.0/24? Also, from your diagram  it looks like the WAN port on router #1 is in the same IP subnet as its LAN side. That will probably not work as the router expects the LAN and WAN side to be on different networks. Assign an IP address from a different range to the WAN port on router #1 and turn off NAT on router #1. Then set up static routes on both routers. Are you sure you need to have separate subnets?

Comment: Router #1 might have firewall that prevents hosts on its WAN side (i.e. your "outer" LAN) from actively reaching its LAN (i.e. the "inner" LAN) host.

Comment: Thank you to all for your suggestions! I finally solved it by disabling SPI Firewall in Router #1.